# CSS resize div whilst maintaining aspect ratio of containing image

Tags: html, css

I have a div container with an img inside of it:

```
<div id='triangle'>
     <img src='/static/triangle.png' style='position: absolute; height: 100%; width: 100%'>
</div>
```

How would I resize the div to a height of 500px and keep the aspect ratio?
I have tried:

```
#triangle 
{
     position: absolute;
     height: 500px;
     width: auto;
}
```

but it does not work: Alternatively:

```
#triangle 
{
     position: absolute;
     max-height: 500px;
     max-width: 500px;
}
```

Creates a div of 500x0 px.

Comment: You must specify height and width of image using `height` and `width` attributs of `<img>` tag.

Comment: Why not you just set image height to 500px and not apply other styles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to apply this style and remove inline-styling from  element:

```
#triangle {
    height:500px;
    width: max-content;
}

img {
    height:100%;
}
```

Comment: When I go on inspect element the img is the desired size, but the div container has a width of 0. Any way I can make the div container the same size as the img?

Comment: For me, this is not the case. Did you remove all inline-styling from <img> tag?

Answer (score 0):

you should Remove "Position: absolute" from image tag. because parent already styled with position: absolute;

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is making one of the width or height attributes of the img tag equal to 100% and the other one equal to auto based on your needs.

Also your img tag must not have `position:absolute` feature. Therefore, your code should look like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            #triangle 
            {
              position: absolute;
              height: 500px;
              width: 500px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>HTML Image</h2>
        <div id="triangle">
            <img src='/static/triangle.png' width="100%" height="auto">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: But in your example the size of the div becomes 500x500, which is not the ratio of the image. What if I wanted to make the div the same size of the image?

Comment: That is not important set the width and height of the div to whatever number that you want. As you set width or height to 100% and the other one to auto the img tag will keep the aspect ratio.